# How to display data in a scroll view using romm persistence in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

Hi I would like to know how can I show my data in a scroll view, I already show the data in a Recycler View but I don't know how to retrieve the data from my database in other components like textview or scroll view

Comment: Do you want just how to use ScrollView?

Comment: No, I want how to show my data in a ScrollView using Room Persistence

Answer (score 0):

database/room has nothing to do with what kind of view you are using for your data, as it seems that you have already shown data from room in recycler view. Just check out the `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` and then load data dynamically into it.

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/ll">


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

now you can add programmatically other views as childs to your linear layout and all would be scrollable.

```
LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
myRoot.addView(view1);
myRoot.addView(view2);
myRoot.addView(view3);
```

the view1, view2, view3 can be text views in which you can show your user names from your ROOM db and it would appear as scrollable.